# Ecto - casting an array of strings to integers in a fragment

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

In an Ecto query I'm running against Postgres (13.6), I need to interpolate a list of ids into a `fragment` - this is generally not something I have a problem with, but in this case, the list of ids is being received as a list of strings that need to be cast to integers (or, more specifically, `BIGINT`). The query that I *think* that I need is as follows, which the troublesome bit being `ANY(ARRAY?::BIGINT[])`:

```
ModelA
|> where(
  [ma],
  fragment(
    "EXISTS (SELECT * FROM model_b mb WHERE mb.a_id = ? AND mb.c_id = ANY(ARRAY?::BIGINT[]))",
    a.id,
    ^c_ids
  )
)
```

where `c_ids` would be a list like `["1449441579", "2345556834"]`

However, when I run this, I get the error

```
(Postgrex.Error) ERROR 42703 (undefined_column) column "array$4" does not exist
```

referring to the generated SQL

```
ANY(ARRAY$4::BIGINT[])
```

Of course, I could convert the array of `c_ids` to integers beforehand in my app code, but I'd like to see if I can get it to cast in the query itself.

Writing the fragment in straight SQL works out just fine:

```
SELECT * FROM model_b mb WHERE mb.a_id = 1 AND mb.c_id = ANY(ARRAY['1449441579', '2345556834']::BIGINT[]);
```

What is the idiomatic way to get this kind of array casting to work in an Ecto fragment? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to codify my comment, I would do the integer conversion before the query.  You can use the `dynamic` macro to support `IN` queries:

```
import Ecto.Query

alias YourApp.Repo
alias YourApp.SomeSchema, as: ModelA

strs = ["1", "2", "3"]

ids = Enum.map(strs, fn x -> String.to_integer(x) end)

conditions = dynamic([tbl], tbl.id in ^ids)

Repo.all(
  from ma in ModelA,
  where: ^conditions
)
|> IO.inspect()
```

Comment: Thanks - this is what I ended up doing in the end. There wasn't a strong reason not to do it this way, it was more of just wanting to know why it wasn't working in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I did find a post that led me to a potential solution here - https://elixirforum.com/t/interpolating-lists-into-ecto-query-fragment-1/16690/7 - however, I'm not convinced that this is optimal for me.

By using `Enum.join` and converting my initial array of strings into a string and then allowing Postgres to cast that string to an array of bigints, it worked out:

```
ModelA
|> where(
  [ma],
  fragment(
    "EXISTS (SELECT * FROM model_b mb WHERE mb.a_id = ? AND mb.c_id = ANY(ARRAY?::BIGINT[]))",
    a.id,
    ^Enum.join(c_ids, ",")
  )
)
```

So I'm posting it here for reference and because it does "work", but I feel sort of silly doing this, because I specifically was trying to avoid processing the list before passing it to PG... so yeah I'd still really like to hear about the "right" way to do this...

Comment: Can't you convert the list into integers BEFORE the query, e.g. `ids = Enum.map(strs, fn x -> String.to_integer(x) end)` and then that in a standard `Ecto` `in` clause?  It seems like doing the conversion in PostGres is the more complex way of handling it, but maybe I'm not following all the constraints for your use case.

Comment: Yes, that is an option, and I may be overcomplicating this. I was just trying to figure out why I couldn't get it to work in an Ecto fragment when it seemed easy enough to accomplish what I needed via raw SQL.